# Multiple linear regression (error) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

i have a dataframe named data1 and it has 10 columns. i create an new data with 3 of the colmuns named PTS, 2P and 3P like this

```
myvars=c("PTS","2P","3P")
data2 <- data1[myvars]
data2
```

I want to use them to make a multiple linear regression model and analyze it. My dependent is PTS and independents are the 2P and 3P. i'm using this command

```
model <- lm(formula=PTS ~ 2P + 3P, data=data2)
model
```

but it shows this error

```
> model <- lm(formula=PTS ~ 2P + 3P, data=data2)  
Error: unexpected symbol in "model <- lm(formula=PTS ~ 2P"   
> model  
Error: object 'model' not found
```

Why is this happening? Can someone please help me?

Comment: you have non-syntactic variable names (ie, begins with digits), try backticks `lm(formula=PTS ~ \`2P\` + \`3P\`, data=data2)` or nicer variable names, see `?make.names`

Comment: thank you @rawr ,it worked!